# Release date of blockbuster movies and when they actually finish the movie

Tags: production

I see in the news today that [Avengers Infinity War release date has been moved to one week earlier](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/2381461/marvel-surprises-fans-by-moving-avengers-infinity-wars-release-date). I am curious usually how long before release date of movies (blockbuster movies to be more specific) the production is complete, is it matter of days or one month or maybe longer? For example in software engineering we hope to finish the development and testing before the release date to account for unexpected problems or issues. Is there the same concept in movie production?

Comment: Peter Jackson finished editing Fellowship of the Ring two days before its premiere.  But usually films have 3 months or more between completion and release.  There's no fixed rule for the industry.

Comment: @Tim [All the Money in the World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_the_Money_in_the_World) began reshooting exactly one month prior to release. That was a close one.

Comment: Interesting articles: [Wikipedia#Film distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_distribution#Film_release), [Wikipedia#Art release](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_release#Film) and [Wikipedia#Filmmaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filmmaking#Distribution).

Comment: What's "finished"? George Lucas kept tinkering with the SW prequels even after they were released. For at least one of the prequels the analogue version of the movie playing in theaters was slightly different from the digital one because Lucas kept tinkering and the digital version could be delivered later. For the second prequel the DVD was leaked online two months after the movie's release in theaters and that one was also different from the movie as released...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joss Whedon shot Avengers post-credit scene on the day of premiere. Ridley Scott didn't finished his "Blade Runner" till 25 years after it's premiere in 1982.

There's a difference between studio desired release date and creator(s) feel and need to finish the movie.
Studios release date is usually calculated based on time needed to shot the movie, montage, reshooting some scenes, adding FX, preparing marketing materials, preparing copies, sending movies to different countries if they are distributed there, securing actors time to promote the movie AND THEN figuring out if the movie won't collide with any other premiere so first weekend won't be a flop.
And then all those calculations goes into the gutter because the new guy hired to do just montage decide he need to put CGI clean upper lip on guys moustache.

In the Avengers case the push to one week earlier may by dictated by the premiere of Deadpool and Solo movies. So to "wear" the movie in cinemas and earn more money before next thing will arrive and take a portion of audience.